# computational benefit of using hdf5 for deep learning

Tags: database, deep-learning, storage, hdf5

In several instances hdf5 storage format is used for deep learning. The benefit of hdf5 to share data can be understood. However, can I expect to gain efficiency while training by using hd5f rather than image of concatenated frames?

If sharing is least of my concerns, is there any reason why I should use hdf5?

Edit:
I explored various pages such as HDF5 user's guide and FAQ and other blog posts. I found hdf5 is primarily a versatile storage format. I could not find them discuss details about efficiency in the context I am concerned.

Comment: does your mentioned efficiency in paragraph 2 refer to faster training speeds or storage savings?

Comment: @pietz, sorry for being unclear. I am concerned with training speed only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked with images, videos, audio recording, text, and even 3D MRIs. I've never come across a situation where the reading speed of the data is the bottleneck in the pipeline.

However, one advantage of storing the dataset in something like hdf5 is that an initial loading to memory is a lot faster than reading thousands of files individually. I usually use a cloud service to synchronize my data, where one big file is also a lot more convenient than a million small ones.

Other than that I cannot think of efficiency benefits of using hdf5.